# Gravity Forms Datepicker - Restricting Days - Code only works after pressing submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm trying to use the gform_datepicker_options_pre_init hook to restrict dates to just weekdays and also disable previous dates. I have the code and can see that it works but the issue I have is that the dates are only greyed out after hitting the submit button after the form is not fully completed. On first load, all dates are selectable.

I have the code in a HTML field which I have tried in various positions in the form. It's currently the first field at the top of the page.

```
<script >

gform.addFilter('gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function(optionsObj, formId, fieldId) {

if ( formId == 93 && fieldId == 12 ) {
optionsObj.firstDay = 1;
        optionsObj.beforeShowDay = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends;
    optionsObj.minDate = 0;
}//endif

    return optionsObj;
} );

</script>
```

Expecting that the date fields should be greyed out when the form is first loaded stopping users from selecting weekends and previous dates.

Comment: Have you checked the JS console for errors? Not sure what exactly what you mean by the “HTML field”, but it sounds like it might be a simple case of execution of stuff in the wrong order.

Comment: That's a really good point. Of everything I've been looking at, I didn't look at the console. Turns out there's an error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: gform is not defined'. Now to try and work out what/how/why.

Comment: Just going to leave this here for you if you want to go the easy route: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-limit-dates/ 

Comment: thanks David, I did see that one but unfortunately there isn't a budget at the moment for this project. Two thumbs up though for the marketing ;)

Comment: Just in case someone else has any ideas, I have managed to get rid of the console errors but the same problem still persists. The datepicker renders ok on first load but all dates are still selectable. Only after hitting the 'submit' button when the warning saying required fields need to be completed does the datepicker then grey out weekends and previous days. *scratching head*